# Python/Django/MySQL optimisation

Tags: python, mysql, django, logic

Just a logic question really...I have a script that takes rows of data from a CSV, parses the cell values to uniform the data and makes a check on the database that a key/primary value does not exist so as to prevent duplicates!  At the moment, the 1st 10-15k entries commit to the DB fairly quick but then it starts really slowing as there are more entries in the DB to check against for duplicates....by the time there are 100k rows in the DB the commit speed is about 1/sec argh...

So my question, is it (pythonically) more efficient to extract and parse the data separately to the DB commit procedure (maybe in a class based script or?? Could I add multiprocessing to the csv parsing or DB commit) and is there a quicker method to check the database for duplicates if i am only cross-referencing 1 table and 1 value??

Much appreciated

Kuda

Answer (score 0):

If the first 10-15k entries worked fine, probably the issue is with the database query. Do you have a suitable index, and is that index used by the database? You can use an `EXPLAIN` statement to see what the database is doing, whether it's actually using the index for the particular query used by Django.

If the table starts empty, it might also help to run `ANALYZE TABLE` after the first few thousand rows; the query optimiser might have stale statistics from when the table was empty. To test this hypothesis, you can connect to the database while the script is running, when it starts to slow down, and run `ANALYSE TABLE` manually. If it immediately speeds up, the problem was indeed stale statistics.

As for optimisation of database commits themselves, it probably isn't an issue in your case (since the first 10k rows perform fine), but one aspect is the round-trips; for every query, it has to go to the database and get the results back. This is especially noticeable if the database is across a network. If you need to speed that up, Django has a [`bulk_create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) method to insert many rows at once. However, if you do that, you'll only get an error for the whole batch of rows if you try to insert duplicates forbidden by the database indexes; you'll then have to find the particular row causing the error using other code.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response...not sure i have the answer to most of what you asked.  The query is "check_entry = ("SELECT id FROM rrn WHERE rrn = %s")
    check_data = self.all_rrn[x]
    self.cursor.execute(check_entry, (check_data, ))
    rrnOutput = self.cursor.fetchone() ......" and if there is an output I know its a duplicate...  How would I know what the index is and where can i run the analyze table please??

Comment: the bulk_create would be nice but the data is so all over the place it seems best to insert each section after ensuring integrity of the data...maybe i'm wrong i dunno lol

Comment: The index is in the database; if you haven't touched the database, and `rrn` is not the primary key, there probably isn't one. You can add it via Django by adding `db_index=True` in the field definition (then creating a migration and running it, see Django docs).

Comment: To connect to the database, you can either use the command-line `mysql` tool, or one of the GUI interfaces. Either way, you give it the relevant connection parameters (similar to the Django database configuration), it connects to the database, then you can run manual queries and other SQL commands, including `ANALYZE TABLE rrn`. If you haven't used `EXPLAIN` before, you'll probably want to look for a tutorial on interpreting the results; reading them is its own skill.

Comment: Hmm, looks like I misspelled `db_index` and `ANALYZE TABLE` the first time; now fixed.

Comment: That works brilliant dude, added some indexing to the database (as well as I tidied up the insert statements a little) and now it is plodding along at a fairly reasonable rate but most importantly it's not slowing down so....Much Appreciated!!

Comment: would leave you a positive feedback up but I can't yet but thanks anyway dude! :)

Comment: @Kuda_ - You should be able to accept the answer, if you found it the useful one? That also counts as positive feedback...